# Which yum package will provide "GTK+ peers"?

Tags: linux, centos, gtk, xorg, centos7

Getting a compilation error during make gcc-4.9.2 in CentOS 7:

```
configure: error: GTK+ peers requested but no X library available
```

I'm guessing that my base CentOS 7 installation didn't come with everything required, but rather than just yum install randomly in hopes of getting it right, I'm hoping someone can tell me which package specifically will satisfy this error.

Here are my currently installed gtk packages:

```
gtk+-1.2.10-77.el7.x86_64
gtk2-2.24.22-5.el7_0.1.i686
gtk2-2.24.22-5.el7_0.1.x86_64
gtk2-devel-2.24.22-5.el7_0.1.x86_64
gtk2-devel-docs-2.24.22-5.el7_0.1.x86_64
gtk2-immodule-xim-2.24.22-5.el7_0.1.x86_64
gtk3-3.8.8-5.el7.x86_64
gtk3-devel-3.8.8-5.el7.x86_64
gtk3-immodule-xim-3.8.8-5.el7.x86_64
gtkhtml3-4.6.6-3.el7.x86_64
gtkmm24-2.24.2-8.el7.x86_64
gtkmm30-3.8.1-3.el7.x86_64
gtksourceview3-3.8.1-4.el7.x86_64
gtkspell-2.0.16-8.el7.x86_64
gtk-vnc2-0.5.2-7.el7.x86_64
```

And here are my currently installed xorg packages:

```
xorg-x11-apps-7.7-6.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-docs-1.6-7.el7.noarch
xorg-x11-drivers-7.7-6.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-ati-7.2.0-9.20140113git3213df1.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-dummy-0.3.6-15.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-evdev-2.8.2-5.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-fbdev-0.4.3-15.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.21.15-13.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-modesetting-0.8.0-13.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-nouveau-1.0.10-5.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-qxl-0.1.1-9.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.7.1-10.el7_0.1.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-v4l-0.2.0-35.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-vesa-2.3.2-14.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-vmmouse-13.0.0-10.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-vmware-13.0.1-7.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-void-1.4.0-23.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-wacom-0.23.0-6.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi-7.5-9.el7.noarch
xorg-x11-fonts-ISO8859-1-100dpi-7.5-9.el7.noarch
xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.5-9.el7.noarch
xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-18.1.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-glamor-0.5.1-4.20140115gitfb4d046c.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-proto-devel-7.7-8.el7.1.noarch
xorg-x11-server-common-1.15.0-7.el7_0.3.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-utils-7.7-4.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.15.0-7.el7_0.3.x86_64
xorg-x11-utils-7.5-13.1.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.7-6.1.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-xbitmaps-1.1.1-6.el7.noarch
xorg-x11-xinit-1.3.2-13.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-xkb-utils-7.7-9.1.el7.x86_64
libX11-common-1.6.0-2.1.el7.noarch
libX11-1.6.0-2.1.el7.i686
libX11-1.6.0-2.1.el7.x86_64
libX11-devel-1.6.0-2.1.el7.x86_64
libXt-1.1.4-6.1.el7.x86_64
libXt-devel-1.1.4-6.1.el7.x86_64
libXtst-devel-1.2.2-2.1.el7.i686
libXtst-devel-1.2.2-2.1.el7.x86_64
libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el7.i686
libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el7.x86_64
```

I'm aware that there is a "--disable-peers" or some other type of configuration option to get around this.  However, I'm trying to build this with the same configuration options that we used in our RHEL6 environment, to introduce as few changes to users as possible when we migrate to CentOS 7.  In that RHEL6 installation (and the above failed CentOS 7 installation), we used the following configuration options:

```
gcc-4.9.2/configure --prefix=/usr/local/pkg/gcc/4.9.2 \
                    --enable-bootstrap \
                    --enable-shared \
                    --enable-threads=posix \
                    --enable-checking=release \
                    --with-system-zlib \
                    --enable-__cxa_atexit \
                    --enable-gnu-unique-object \
                    --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go \
                    --enable-java-awt=gtk \
                    --disable-dssi \
                    --with-cloog \
                    --with-tune=generic \
                    --with-arch_32=i686 \
                    --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
```

Comment: Can you peek into either the configure or configure.ac file to see what it's checking for? And what software are you building again? I don't remember gcc having a GTK+ dependency...

Comment: It's gcc 4.9.2, and I think the GTK+ dependency might come from the configuration option: "--enable-java-awt=gtk".  Looking through configure and configure.ac for the libjava/classpath part of gcc 4.9.2, which is failing, the error is thrown when a variable called "$no_x" tests as yes.  I'm trying to make heads or tails of how $no_x is set, but I'm having a tough time :/

Comment: Nothing in configure.ac? That should be easier to read...

Comment: The same thing in configure.ac: if test "$no_x" = yes; then AC_MSG_ERROR([GTK+ peers requested but no X library available]) fi But in configure.ac, there are no other instances of "no_x".

Comment: What OS are you running? Are you running this on a GUI system?

Comment: This is CentOS 7.  The machine has GUI/X capabilities, but I'm doing this from bash.

Comment: Doing it from bash won't make a difference. I don't know if CentOS stores the X headers in a separate package (which is why I asked if you had X installed already); you might want to see if there's some sort of `xorg-devel` package or similar...?

Comment: Actually I see you have some of the X11 development packages installed already :S IDK; sorry :/